# Excel sheet modifies with URL

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula

I have a Javascript page URL (snippet bellow). And I am looking for a way to make an individual excel cell link to what ever number appears on the corresponding URL.

So for example I have a cell which is for `a_quantity_in_stock_S` and I want 2 to appear. Unless the Javascript page alters online.

```
var a_quantity_in_stock_S = 2
var a_quantity_in_stock_M = 2
var a_quantity_in_stock_L = 1

var b_quantity_in_stock_S = 2
var b_quantity_in_stock_M = 2
var b_quantity_in_stock_L = 1
```

### Formula idea:

1) Look for `var a_quantity_in_stock_S` through URL.

2) Pick number that it is equal to. (2)

3) Put the number (2) on the cell which the function is applied too.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you're looking for:

**1)** Set up a lookup table for the URL pieces and their number (e.g. A1 is "a_quantity_in_stock_S" and B1 is 2).

**2)** Use this array formula* to generate a custom link that pulls in the right number (assumes URL is in A10):

```
=HYPERLINK(A10&"/"&INDEX(B1:B6,LARGE(- -ISNUMBER(FIND($A$1:$A$6,RIGHT(A$10,LEN($A$1:$A$6))))*ROW(A1:A6),1)))
```

*To create an array formula, you must press **ctrl** + **shift** + **enter**.

Here's what's going on.

```
LARGE(- -ISNUMBER(FIND($A$1:$A$6,RIGHT(A$10,LEN($A$1:$A$6))))*ROW(A1:A6),1)
```

This is examining the list of possible URLs (A1:A6) and seeing if it can find those inside the actual URL (A10). If it gets a match, it returns the number of the item (e.g. 4 means the fourth item in the list matched)

```
INDEX(B1:B6,...
```

Then we use Index to look at column B (where our numbers are listed) and find the corresponding entry and return it. Now we have the number that needs to go with the URL.

```
=HYPERLINK(A10&"/"&...
```

Finally, we create a hyperlink that adds the number to the end of the actual URL. I wasn't sure what format you wanted, so I went with an example like "blah.com/store/b_quantity_in_stock_S/2"

Hope this helps!